# Can a Markov Chain have a limiting distribution and more than 1 stationary distribution?

Tags: markov-process, asymptotics

Can a Discrete-Time Markov Chain have a limiting distribution and more than 1 stationary distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a Markov chain $x_n$ on $\{-1,1\}$. Let the initial distribution $\mu_0$ take the value $x = 1$ with probability $p$ and $x = -1$ with probability $1-p$.

Consider then the transition matrix
$$   P=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right].$$

Depending on whether $x_0 = 1$ or $x_0 = -1$ the chain remain stuck indefinitely in whatever it hit with probability $1$, and therefore the chain has a limiting distribution and two different stationary distributions.

Comment: There's also a more complicated example in this recent question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504320/can-a-markov-chain-have-a-limiting-distribution-and-more-than-1-stationary-distr/504323#504323

Comment: Hehe, thanks @ThomasLumley, my example is so absurdly trivial it might be beyond useful - but it can maybe be considered a minimal reproducible example. Oh, btw, your link is to this question.

Comment: @Forgottenscience the definition of limiting distribution i'm using is the limit as the power of the transition matrix goes to infinity should converge to a matrix with equal rows. This example wouldn't have equal rows. Is my definition wrong or am i misunderstanding something

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For the chain to have a unique limiting distribution it has to be irreducible, which this chain isn't (it's two disconnected states).  A distribution over states is only a limiting distribution if the chain converges to it from any  initial distribution. So, if there are two stationary distributions, you cannot have a limiting distribution.